# Align three images vertically at the top, using the tallest height with floatrow

Tags: vertical-alignment, floatrow

I am using the following LaTeX, to try to get 3 images aligned at the top

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.8cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url, floatrow, caption, fancyhdr, pifont, adjustbox, array, longtable, tikz}
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}

\floatsetup{heightadjust=object}

\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
    >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
    l%
    <{\egroup}%
}

\newcommand*\rot{\multicolumn{1}{R{45}{1em}}}%

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{floatrow}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig:dummy-1}}{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{old_engine/paper1.png}
      }
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig:dummy-2}}{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{old_engine/paper2.png}
      }
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig:dummy-3}}{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{old_engine/paper3.png}
      }
    \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, it acts rather strange (The three images are all cropped to have zero white space at the top).

1. The first image is pushed a little bit down
2. The third image is goes through the caption

What I would like is that the floatrow gets the height of the "tallest" image, where each image is clipped to the top of their ffigbox.

[image]

**EDIT**

This is how it should be.. however it is the exact same code, just with different images. HOW LATEX??

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please add a complete MWE. Is the floatrow mandatory?

Comment: I am sorry, what does MWE? Stand for. I am also not sure if floatrow is necessary, but it looked like something to do the trick. If you can solve my problem without floatrow I would be happy to hear it!

Comment: MWE stands for Minimum Work Example. It is a minimal fully compilable code, with the document class and packages that you use, for us to replicate your problem. As I understood you want 3 images aligned at top, is that correct?

Comment: I added all packages I use. To answer your question, yes I want the three images to be aligned at the top. The captions aligned at the bottom, but not through my images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change my `\rule{}{}` with yours `\includegraphics[]{}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.8cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url, floatrow, caption, fancyhdr, pifont, adjustbox, array, longtable, tikz}
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}

\floatsetup{heightadjust=object}

\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
    >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
    l%
    <{\egroup}%
}

\newcommand*\rot{\multicolumn{1}{R{45}{1em}}}%

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{floatrow}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][\FBheight][t]{\caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig:dummy-1}}{%
    \rule{0.33\textwidth}{80pt}
  }
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][\FBheight][t]{\caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig:dummy-2}}{%
    \rule{0.33\textwidth}{200pt}
  }
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][\FBheight][t]{\caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig:dummy-3}}{%
    \rule{0.33\textwidth}{120pt}
  }
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works for aligning them to the top, but my images still go through the captions. Did you add any packages?

Comment: @Tessmore I updated my answer. You can work with `\FBheight` to get the legend correctly aligned.

Comment: Edited my question. As you can see your solution does seem to help... however, it is still not working for my particular problem in the same latex file. Tried compiling 100 times..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, yet using `subfloatrow`. After lots of experiments and random code changes, I learned the following:
This problem only shows up, when the third(!) image has the larges height.
The only solution I found was manually setting the height of all(!) three `ffigbox`. Unfortunately the hight is not automatically detected. It might be possible to automatically calculate the padding, though. In the example it's `20px`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{floatrow, caption, adjustbox}


\floatsetup{heightadjust=object}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{floatrow}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][220pt][t]{\caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig:dummy-1}}{%
    \rule{0.33\textwidth}{80pt}
  }
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][220pt][t]{\caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig:dummy-2}}{%
    \rule{0.33\textwidth}{120pt}
  }
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][220pt][t]{\caption{Dummy figured}\label{fig:dummy-3}}{%
    \rule{0.33\textwidth}{200pt}
  }
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While this might solve the problem, please post complete examples, not only fragments